# Will keys and values of a hash have the same "order" in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I understand that a hash is not ordered in perl. What I am concerned about is if I can depend on the keys and values coming out with an index relationship.

Say I have this hash

```
my %h = ("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3, "d" => 4);
```

If I do `keys %h`, I might get

```
("b", "a", "d", "c")
```

Would I be guaranteed that `values %h` would come out in the same order to match keys? Can I expect?

```
(2, 1, 4, 3)
```

Or is there no guarantee that there's any index relationship between `keys %h` and `values %h`?

Comment: @DaveCross, "RTFM" isn't really an answer.

Comment: Which is why I wrote it as a comment :-) But, seriously, in this case I think it is. The answer you your question is clearly written in the FM. The answer that you have accepted quotes from the FM. So, yes, I do think it's a reasonable answer here.

Comment: If you can't find information like this in the documentation, please file a bug report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. As long as the hash is not changed (insertion or deletion), `keys`, `values` and `each` will keep the same order:

> So long as a given hash is unmodified you may rely on keys, values and each to repeatedly return the same order as each other.
>
> – from [`perldoc -f keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

So you could safely copy a hash like:

```
my %orig = ...;
my %copy;
@copy{keys %orig} = values %orig;
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed to know **^.^**

Comment: But the order changes between invocations.

Answer (score 3):

Although the order that keys and values return their contents can
vary according to machine and implementation, you can count on the
fact that they will both produce the same order.  Alternatively,
you can use the function "each" to pull both keys and values at the
same time:

```
while (($key,$value) = each %ENV) {
    print "$key=$value\n";
}
```

The advantage of using each is that perl won't have to allocate enough
memory for all the keys and values at once, so it will be more efficient
if you are iterating through a large hash.

Comment: Note that depending on your perl version, grabbing the list of keys and then looking each one up in the hash may actually be faster than using `each`.  I do not know how or why, but test before you "optimize"..

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I could believe what you say about `keys` vs. `each`.  I believe that when perl implements `foreach my key (keys %myhash)`, it doesn't actually expand out all the keys at once, but does them singly.

Comment: @Mark Nodine, `foreach my key (keys %myhash)` flattens the list of keys

Comment: @ikegami - what do you mean?  Keys of a hash are stringified at insertion time; there's nothing to flatten..

Comment: @Mark Reed, Flattening a list means evaluating each item of a list (in this case, just `keys`) to form a "flat" list of scalars on the stack. e.g. `@a,@b,@c` creates a "flat" list consisting of the elements of `@a`, `@b` and `@c`. Mark Nodine said he though `foreach my key (keys %myhash)` was optimized into something like `while (my ($key) = keys(%myhash))`, and I told him it wasn't.

Comment: @ikegami: You are apparently correct that perl does not optimize the keys when iterating.  I just did an experiment where I generated a hash with all keys `"aaaaa" .. "zzzzz"` and the `keys` implementation used 50% more memory than `each` did, but was only 5% slower.  I think perl can't do such an optimization since you may modify the keys in the loop itself.